# Which chapter in Skanda Purana contains the greatness of Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, skanda-purana

Is there any conversation in Skanda Purana between Narada and Sanatkumara about the greatness of Ramayana?

If yes, then what is the number and name of the chapter?

Comment: I’m sorry. May have linked a Hindi one. Gita press sells English Valmiki Ramayana too but one will have to buy that (online order or go to the shop). The English one isn’t available online

Comment: Just generally. Do you know Hindi as per the answer below?

Comment: @Archit Difficult, but manageable...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is supposedly a section called Uttarakhaṇḍa of the Skanda Purāṇa that purportedly contains what is called the Rāmāyaṇamahātmyam. The Valmiki Ramayana published by Gita Press Gorakhpur has this mahatmya at the beginning of the book. According to it, this is a conversion between Narada and Sanatkumara describing the greatness of hearing Ramayana, fitted into 5 chapters:-

1. Chapter 1: Kalpanukīrtanam - on being asked by the sages, Suta tells them that Ramayana helps in avoiding the ill effects of Kaliyuga
2. Chapter 2: Rākṣasamokṣaṇam - here starts the actual conversation between Sanatkumara and Narada. Hereby listening to the Ramayana, a rakshasa is relieved of his demonic form.
3. Chapter 3: Māghaphalānukīrtanam - the benefit of hearing Ramayana in Magha month. A story of the previous birth of King Sumati and Queen, who by hearing the Ramayana reached Shri Rama’s abode.
4. Chapter 4: Chaitramāsaphalānukīrtanam - the benefit of hearing Ramayana in the month of Chaitra. A story of a hunter named Kalika and Uttanka muni is told, where the hunter’s sins are destroyed.
5. Chapter 5: Phalānukīrtanam - Narada tells sanatkumara about the manner in which the Ramayana is to be heard over nine days (like you have navahnaparayana for Ramcharitmanas). He also explains the phala as also does Suta while concluding the mahatmya.

Refer in Hindi : [The Valmiki Ramayana by Gita Press containing the Rāmāyaṇamahātmyam](https://archive.org/stream/HindiBookValmikiRamayanPartIByGitaPress/Hindi%20Book-Valmiki-Ramayan-Part-I%20by%20Gita%20Press#page/n20/mode/1up)

[image]

---

Now one must wonder why words such as ‘purported’ and ‘supposed’ have been used above: the Skanda Purana available today is composed of 7 khandas, in which this Uttarakhaṇḍa finds no place. Even the [Skanda Purana by Gita press](https://archive.org/details/skanda-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n11/mode/2up) doesn’t have this mahatmya or the Uttarakhaṇḍa. It is said that another name for the Brahmottarakhaṇḍa is Uttarakhaṇḍa but that too doesn’t contain this mahatmya. We must remember Skanda purana is a collection of various almost disconnected manuscripts and hence this text must be part of a khanda not included.

Comment: Or could it be part of the Samhita version of Skanda Purana?

Comment: @Surya possible, it could be part of the Vaishnava samhita but apparently that’s not available in India, so it’s not so likely. Or like Sahyadri Khanda it never made it into the khanda version?